# how do I disable auto indenting and code completion in ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

When you type `<div>` and press enter on the standard ace editor (in html mode) it automatically creates a closing div tag and indents the cursor. You can see it [here](http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=about).

They have disabled it for the [kitchen sink](http://ace.ajax.org/build/kitchen-sink.html) which is what I am after.

Is their a simple property setting like

```
editor.autoIndent = false;
editor.autoComplete = false;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `editor.setBehavioursEnabled(false)`
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/kitchen-sink/demo.js#L353

Comment: this question was asked when ace didn't have real autocomplete, and is about automatic bracket pairing. If you are asking about autocomplete popup it can be disabled with `editor.setOptions(enableLiveAutocompletion: false})` if it doesn't work, please give a link to your code or a jsbin with demo.

Comment: and to completely disable it

`editor.setOptions({enableBasicAutocompletion: false, enableLiveAutocompletion: false});`